# Bounded perturbation of self-adjoint operator. Where is the spectrum?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory

In [these](https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/MATHPHYS/veselic/downloads/indef.pdf) notes, the following claim is made:

Let $H$ be self-adjoint and $A$ bounded then the spectrum of

$$T=H+A$$ is contained in

$$\sigma(T)\subset\{ \lambda; d(\lambda, \sigma(H))\le \Vert A \vert \}.$$

However, I could find no other reference for that statement, so I wonder whether it is true and if so, where I can find a proof. I should say that the non-trivial aspect of this statement is really that $A$ is not assumed to be symmetric, too.

Comment: I would suspect that the first citation referred to, namely *Kato, T., Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators, Springer, Berlin 1966.* has such a result.  Kato's text is famously very comprehensive on perturbation theory results.

Comment: It seems that from the context, it might be implies that $A$ is also self-adjoint.

Comment: See Th. 4.10 pag. 291 of Kato.

Comment: @Emilio This assumes that $A$ is symmetric, which is not made explicit in the context of the linked paper

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that's exactly the question, does $A$ have to be self-adjoint?

Comment: Read through the rest of the paper.  If they never reference adding a non-self-adjoint perturbation, then it very likely a simple mistake of not mentioning this condition on $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom okay, but is the result then clearly false?

Comment: Not "clearly", but I suspect that it is indeed false.  In fact, I would suspect that it fails in the finite dimensional case.